# When two segments between two parallel lines have the same length, are they always parallel?

Tags: geometry

[image]

This seems like such an elemental thing to me, but I don't want to assume it's always true, since there could be an exception. Also, without knowing the length of $a$, if $\alpha=\beta$, then the lines are parallel too, right? Thank you.

Comment: Reflect one of them across a line perpendicular to the two horizontal lines.

Comment: @JohnDouma Ah, that was easy to see, damn. Are there infinite cases?

Comment: Drawing a circle with radius $a$ and center on one of the lines reveals that there are only those two possibilities. Although there are infinitely many translations of each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your drawing, mark the 8 points from A to H, starting with the bottom left one and then going counterclockwise. You know that if the size of angle ABG is a, then GBC is 180-a. Expand lines GB and FC over points C and B. If those two lines cross in a point X, the angle BXC will be of size 0 (since XBC is a and XCB is 180-a).
Therefore, you conclude that lines GB and FC dont cross on the plane below AD.

You can conclude they dont cross above HE either similarly. Thus, GB and FC dont cross at all, which is the definition of two parallel lines.

Now, you can determine all angles in the polygon BCFG. Connect F and B, and calculate the angles created by such a line, and you'll be able to show that triangles GFB and BCF are congruent (same side BF, same angles CBF and BFG, same angles GBF and CFB), so therefore GB = FC.

Now, this is only the case if the angles a are oriented on the same side. If the initial angles a are opposite to eachother, ie not facing the same direction, then the quadrilateral will be a bilateral trapezoid, so the two lines will still be the same length, but won't be parallel (unless a = 90).

Comment: How does this behave in the case of a reflection?

Comment: What exact reflection do you mean, what's the axis?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear: A perpendicular to one of the parallels*, like one commenter said.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't know what you mean. If you mean an axis being a perpendicular to parallel lines for which we initially know are parallel, in case of the other two lines getting reflected, all of the angles would still be the same, the ones that are a and the ones that are 180-a, and thus the lines would still be parallel with one another, have equal length, and have equal distances between them on the first two parallel lines.

Comment: I'm referring to reflecting only one of them, thus basically having the sides of an isosceles triangle, like the first commenter of my original post. Sorry if I'm being unclear, geometry is pretty difficult to me.

Comment: In the case that only a single line is mirrored, then the angles inside the quadrilateral on the same parallel will be the same. On one of the parallels the angles will be a, while on the other the angles will be 180-a, so unless angle a is 90, the two lines wont be parallel. So it's true that if two lines between parallel lines have the same length, that they are not always immediately parallel, but depending on the picture of the problem you're solving, it should be rather obvious if the lines are parallel or if they are parts of a bilateral triangle, so you should continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Construct an isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ with equal sides $AB$ and $BC$, and construct a line through $B$ parallel to $AC$. Then $AB$ and $BC$ are equal segments between parallel lines that are not parallel.

Comment: So, to assume that they are parallel to each other, I'd have to have the information that they have the same angle, right? But then I'd not even need the length, I suppose. Are there parallel segments (in this situation) that don't have the same length?

Comment: @NickCassol If the segments are parallel, they must have the same length, because opposite sides of a parallelogram are congruent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

take $\beta=180°-\alpha$, what about the two segments?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the case $L_1 := \pmatrix{\mathbb{R}\\ 0}$ and $L_2 := \pmatrix{\mathbb{R}\\ 1}$. A line segment of length $a$ between those parallel lines implies $a^2 - 1= x^2$. Now construct the two vectors $\pmatrix{\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\\1}$ and $\pmatrix{-\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\\1}$, so the scalar product is $-(a^2 + 1) + 1 = -a^2 < 0$. But parallel vectors would have scalar product $> 0$.